# Java Webdrivermanager change properties folder

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I use Webdrivermanager to update to the latest Webdriver version. In Python I was able to modify the module myself. But I have not that much experience in Java yet. I use this to change the Driver download folder: [Have WebDriverManager Download to Specific Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397766/have-webdrivermanager-download-to-specific-directory).
But the resolution.properties file is still saving under the ".cache" folder. How can i change its location too and do I even need the file?

I hop you can help me out.

Best Regards

Christian

Comment: should be resolutionCachePath: https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#advanced-configuration  So WebDriverManager.chromedriver().resolutionCachePath("YourFolder").avoidOutputTree().setup(); ?

Comment: nop doesn't change it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Invoke WebDriverManager as follows:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().cachePath("/your/path").setup();
```

If in addition you want to avoid storing the drivers in a tree folder structure, use the following:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().cachePath("/your/path").avoidOutputTree().setup();
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I am using just like you posted in the Post I linked above. But it still saves the "resolution.properties" in the "~.cache/selenium" Folder